# multiple levels of float:left is this correct way to do this?

Tags: css

I have to write an admin piece and the basic design has a set of rows that look like this (not for scale):

[image]

I am thinking of doing two sets of float:left's like this: http://jsbin.com/sizaw/1/edit?html,css,output  Is this the common / recommended way of doing this or is there some better way?

### edit #1

I guess is there a better more html5'y way of doing this? the float:left seems so kludgy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

Html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
div {
    min-width: 70px;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

<kbd>**[Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Dx8ws/)**</kbd>

***Edit:***
<kbd>**[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Dx8ws/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: +1 for clean and simple. BTW: inline-block can cause unexpected spacing problems with whitespaces. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Dx8ws/1/

Comment: Add `vertical-align: middle` to make it more perfect :)